# Java Bukkit value function

Tags: java, bukkit

Hello have problem with the value string and cant compile cause of this

screenshot of the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/laGkq.png
can someone help? thanks!

Comment: Please add more code and error logs. It's pretty hard to help you with such small amount of information.

Comment: i dont have more errors / logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a generic type to a value in Java since it needs to know what's being set in the memory (for the length).

For more information, you should read a bit about [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

It's hard without the that small amount of code to tell, but normally, if you remove the `(T)`, you should not get that error.